# Windows print clients resist & autorevert network printer configuration

Tags: windows-10, printer, network-printer

We have a HP Laserjet P2055dn running on a local Linux (Ubuntu 22.04) server running Samba. It is well configured (*i.e.*, works locally as configured, is shared to the right clients, which can access and print to it).  This configuration includes being fully configured for two-sided printing.  This configuration has just worked for years.

The trouble is, Windows 10 clients recently:

- resist configuration of this printer for two-sided printing; and
- autorevert their configuration so as to disable two-sided printing.

In particular, in Control Panel > Devices and Printers > Printing Preferences > Printing Shortcuts > General Everyday Printing, setting "Print on both sides" to "Yes, flip over" and then clicking "Apply", then "OK" both

- has no effect; and
- autoreverts to "No" when re-opened.

The same configuration resistance / autoreversion also occurs with the "Print on both sides" checkbox on the Finishing tab.

Deleting the printer and instead installing today's HP Universal Print Driver from the HP site is worse:

- No Printing Shortcuts exist at all, nor does any means exist to create one; and
- The "Print on both sides" checkbox exhibits the same resistance / autoreversion behavior.

Any thoughts about how to get the Windows clients to observe and persist their configuration of the network printer for two-sided printing, would be especially welcome.

Comment: I would try "Printer properties" instead.  Then preferences, and then "Finishing" and set "Print on both sides" here.  Then again under "Advanced" and "Printing Defaults" and then "Finishing" and "Print on both sides".  Don't forget to **apply** your settings on each screen before moving to the next.

Comment: As an administrator open the Printer Settings dialog, select "Device Settings" and  make sure Automatic Duplex Unit is set to **Installed** rather than Not installed.

Comment: @DavidPostill, but way ahead of you.  Just to confirm, Properties > Device Settings > Installable Options > Duplex Unit (for 2-Sided Printing): Installed

Comment: @cybernard, thanks.  I previously have observed that launching the configuration GUI from some locations works better than others, including the specific one you suggested, which I repeated again just now.  Configuration now fails in all cases, which is what prompted this post.  I also would note that no "Printing Defaults" branch or option exists under the "Advanced" tab.  A "Printing Shortcuts" tab exists but configuration there also autoreverts.

Comment: Which driver are you using on the PC?  I referred the HP universal driver.

Comment: Printing Defaults would be my first suggestion as well. I can't imagine a driver that does not have the "Printing Defaults" button at bottom left under the Advanced tab. To restate the procedure: right-click the printer and select Printer Properties; click the Advanced tab, and then the Printing Defaults button.

Comment: @hdhondt, it turns out there are two Advanced tabs: (a) Right-click on the printer, select "Printing Preferences" and one appears with no "Default Properties" setting or button.  It simply states, "HP LaserJet P3050 Series PCL6 Advanced Document Settings"  (b) Right-click on the printer, select "Printer Properties" and a different box pops up with its own "Advanced" tab, which does have a "Printing Defaults ..." button. Click on that, and one gets a box perfectly identical to (a) except being captioned "Printing Defaults" instead of "Printing Preferences".  Odd and confusing, but whatever.

Comment: @hdhondt, adding to the confusion is that, in the second case, the General tab has a "Preferences ..." button, which opens the perfectly identical case (a) dialog box.  I guess I never knew the perfectly identical case (b) dialog box existed, and yet I still can imagine no reason why I or anyone else should.  "Preferences" and "Defaults" are semantically identical, just as are the two interfaces.  Chalk this up to a failed user interface, I suppose. I'll post an answer, but thanks.

Comment: Printing Preferences and Printer Properties are different5. Only Printing Properties lets you set defaults for the printer. And yes, the Preferences button in Printing Defaults takes you back to Printing Preferences - but that one does not set defaults either. You MUST go Printer Properties > Advanced tab > Printing Defaults

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that, besides the "Printing Preferences" configuration interface, the HP Universal Print Driver GUI also has a second, perfectly identical "Printing Defaults" configuration interface.

In ten or twelve years of wrestling with this driver, I never noticed that there were two.

And, why would I?

- "Printing Preferences" and "Printing Defaults" mean precisely the same thing.
- The interfaces are perfectly identical, with the same tabs, options, icons, and logos, but for the last word in a lengthy title bar string, one being "Preferences" and the other, "Defaults".  No other distinction or contrast of the two is made anywhere.
- Both interfaces are accessed via the context menu of the printer icon in Control Panel > Devices and Printers.

HP obviously also thinks the two are identical.

Nevertheless, it turns out that the two interfaces have fundamental behavioral differences:

- "Printing Preferences" is a non-functioning, dummy configuration mock-up accessible from many locations, that (a) has no effect on printer configuration and (b) autoreverts the values in its own controls on losing focus.
- "Printing Defaults" is a configuration GUI accessible from a single button on one of eight tabs in the printer properties GUI, that actually does set printing preferences that can be made to persist in narrow circumstances (exiting the configuration GUI immediately upon applying configuration changes), but that also autoreverts the values in its controls upon any further navigation within the configuration interface notwithstanding those revised settings having been expressly applied.

Very much through the looking-glass.  One couldn't make this up on one's own.

So, for users of the HP Universal Printer Driver, the learning is to beware the false "Printing Preferences" and seek instead the fickle "Printing Defaults."

Comment: As per my comments, this is standard in every Windows driver. It is not specific to HP. And, as I also pointed out, only Printing Defaults lets you set defaults.